# How do I get GPU to render scene, even with AMD GPU recognized and selected?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, video-sequence-editor, gpu

As the questions states, I have HIP slected and my AMD Radeon RX 6600 XT checked under System>Preferences AND I have the Render Engine set to Cycles, Feature Set as Supported, and Device as GPU Compute.  When I start to render my video my CPU dials up to 70% usage and my GPU stays at 1.6% in task manager.  Does anyone know why?  I'm running the newest version of blender, 3.4.

Comment: Hi, Dan, and welcome. We're not collectively competent to answer questions on hardware, its configuration, or bugs in the application, here. So this post is off-topic, sorry. If you're confident your configuration is good, this should probably be submitted as a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Task Manager does not report correct usage of the GPU and CPU is still used during GPU render. If you selected the render device and correct render settings like you say, those settings are used during render. So you don't need to do anything else, your described process already uses your GPU.